# What is really M-theory? (non-pertubatively)

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, compactification, duality

I don´t really understand **what [M-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory) is supposed to be**. Going beyond the dualities relating different string theories (for example the common $11-D$ limit of IIA and $E_{8}\times E_{8}$) I don't understand what is really M-theory and why is supposed to exist such a theory. I mean, what is incomplete the theory?

The motivation of this question arises in the context of string compactification and **string landscape**. The current paradigm includes such an enormous range of combinations (choice of: compactification manifold, version of the string theory, bundle/brane configuration, flux, critical point of $V_{eff}$...) which fixes the vacua *in an approximate way* that there would be interesting to know what does it lack in the final formulation of string/M-theory (in this case M-theory).

In this context I do not understand the interest of **Matrix theory** (I would be thankful if someone could explain to me its physical motivation). Although some of the calculations using that formalism are coherent with perturbative M-theory ones; in which sense it is expected to be a generalization of M-theory perturbative limit/11-D SUGRA? (Having in mind it is only formulated in Minkowski spacetime and toroidal compactifications).

The other path for "complete" M-theory is even more obscure for me: **AdS/CFT dualities** does not seem to suggest (for me) a physical idea/motivation for a different theory beyond the dualities between certain theories.

**EDIT 1**:  Regarding the **branes** allowed in M-theory: how it can be a generalization of the five string theories if lots of the branes allowed in them are not present in M-theory (it only allows M2-branes and M5-branes (respectively) electrically and magnetically coupled to the four-field strength of the theory). What happens for example with D7-branes and D3-branes which are a fundamental ingredient to allow realistic string compactifications in IIB-theory? If M-theory is true, they just don't have physical existance?

Comment: While you wait: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=M-theory+non-pertubative - does that provide no answers?

Comment: @Chequez I edited my answer, you might want to have a look. Cheers!!!

Comment: @Konstantinos Yes, I understood the way that M-branes include D-branes by reading the link mentioned in the previous comment (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9906108) and I have confirmed those explanations with your last edit. Thanks!

Comment: Ignatios is a great physicist and a great person. You might also want to look the following link https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9512062. 
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that the questions have definite answers yet, but I think they are great for general discussion.

I am addressing the second question related to the AdS/CFT, and I am quoting -copying and pasting- some known facts from a recent paper. In case one wants to study all the details of the paper, find it below.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08570

and the references therein of course; in particular the eight first ones.

People are trying to calculate beyond the SUGRA corrections to M-theory, in order to get some first lessons on this theory

M-theory arises in the strong coupling limit of type IIA string theory.

It is known that M-theory reduces to $11$d SUGRA at
low energies, and its fundamental degrees of freedom are $2$d and $5$d objects known as M$2$-branes and M$5$-branes, respectively.

The worldvolume theory for M$2$-branes (on an orbifold) was found to be a $3$d superconformal Chern-Simons matter theory with classical
$\mathcal{N} = 6$ supersymmetry.

The M$5$-brane worldvolume theory is expected to be a $6$d superconformal field theory with $OSp(8_{*}|4)$ symmetry; this is usually called the $6$d $(2, 0)$ theory.

If one considers a single M$5$-brane, one can formulate the theory in terms of an Abelian $(2, 0)$ tensor multiplet, consisting of a self-dual $2$-form gauge field, $5$ scalars, and $8$ fermions, but it is not known how to generalize this construction to describe multiple M$5$-branes.

This is where the AdS/CFT enters the game to give a hint. The statement is that the worldvolume theory for a stack of N M$5$-branes is dual to M-theory on $AdS_7 × S^4$ with N units of flux through the $4$-sphere,
which reduces to $11$d SUGRA on this background in the limit large N limit; $N \rightarrow \infty$.

The above limit is the SUGRA approximation.

Recently, people have started thinking ways of going beyond the SUGRA approximation, by using the conformal bootstrap programme. This is how people **hope to gain new insight into M-theory beyond the SUGRA approximation.**

It is elusive yet how one can formulate the $6$d $(2, 0)$ theory, and this is why people are using the superconformal and crossing symmetry to deduce the structure of the $4$-point correlators in this theory.

The implications of the aforementioned symmetries for the $4$-point
correlators of stress tensor multiplets in the $6$d $(2, 0)$, adapting the holographic arguments, have showed that these solutions scale in the large-N limit. The spin-$0$ solution scales like $N^{−5}$, all higher-spin
solutions are suppressed by at least $N^{−19/3}$. As a result, the spin-$0$ solution corresponds to the leading correction to the supergravity prediction for the $4$-point correlator (which scales
like $N^{−3}$) and all higher-spin solutions are subleading compared to the $1$-loop supergravity prediction (which scales like $N^{−6}$ but has not been computed yet).

The lessons are about the low energy effective action of M-theory on $AdS^7 \times S_4$. In particular, noting that the anomalous dimensions of the spin-$0$ solution scale like $n^6$ compared to those of the SUGRA prediction (where n is the twist), this suggests that the corresponding terms in the effective action contain six more derivatives than the SUGRA Lagrangian, and are subsequently of the form $\mathcal{R}^4$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is the Riemann tensor.

Edit: M-branes and D-branes.

Punchline: The M-branes realize all D-branes, and this is why D-branes are consistent objects that you don't need to throw away.

Eleven-dimensional supergravity has only an anti-symmetric tensor field $A_{(3)}$ -the rank of the tensor is 3- and the realisation of branes is restricted.

The consistent supergravity solutions are known as M$2$ and M$5$. The are further solutions to classical supergravity known as F$1$ -the fundamental string- and its magnetic dual the NS$5$-brane.

You can classify the theories based on the type of supergravity theory you get in the classical limit.

The way that M-theory sees D-branes is via the net of dualities.

All of the D-branes and the NS$5$ brane are solutions to type II theories, both A and B.

When you reduce the M-theory on a circle, you get back to TypeIIA. TypeIIA is the same as TypeIIB when you perform a T-duality. The M$2$ and M$5$ branes reduce to the various D-branes and S-dualizing the D$5$ brane you get the NS$5$. I don't remember the actual dualities you need to apply, but you can go to the seminal papers and look there for more detailed answers.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought it would be ok, since it is an arXiv file. I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the information, it is very useful. Some questions, though: regarding the branes allowed in M-theory:  how it can be a generalization of the five string theories if lots of the branes allowed in them are not present in M-theory (it only allows M2-branes and M5-branes (respectively) electrically and magnetically coupled to the four-field strength of the theory). What happens for example with D7-branes  and D3-branes which are a fundamental ingredient to allow realistic string compactifications in IIB-theory? If M-theory is true, they just don't have physical  existance ?

Comment: No worries. Glad you liked it. I will try to answer to your question on M and D branes when I get back home, as I am swamped right now. Sorry for that. 

By the way, I think -I am not quite sure- that it is one of the rules that each question will have a different topic, so you might want to ask a new one about branes. 

Cheers!!!

Comment: Sorry, I have not replied yet, but I am working on a project that consumes most of my time and energy; I saw the edit thoug. I will get back to this question as soon as possible. Thanks for the understanding. Cheers!!!

Comment: To answer to @Chequez: The branes in string theory are supposed to all arise from branes and other structures in M-theory by various limits. For instance the NS1, D2, D4, and NS5 arise directly from the M2 and M5 by double dimensional reduction (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+dimensional+reduction) the D6 arises from the 11d KK-monopole (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-theory+lift+of+gauge+enhancement+on+D6-branes) , the D1, D3, D5, D7 arise from these in turn by T-duality.